# Why am I getting this python concatenation error?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I am doing this tutorial and I've run into this weird bug. I am printout the date.

So before the sample codes, you need to have:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

this will print

```
print "%s" "/" "%s" "/" "%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

So will this

```
print "pizza" + "pie"
```

so will this

```
print "%s/%s/%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

But when I introduce concatenating operators:

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "python", line 4, in <module>
#TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
print "%s" + "/" + "%s" + "/" + "%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

Its some kind of concatenation issue. What I don't understand is that the code will print when I concatenate other strings and when I don't use concatenation with the strings that I want.

Comment: Because it's trying to format all your values into the last `"%s"`. You need to wrap the string building in parens.

Comment: it's a simple matter of operator precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is caused by operator precedence.

The following line works because this is [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/string-catenation.html), which has a higher precedence than the `%` operator.

```
print "%s" "/" "%s" "/" "%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

The following does NOT work because the `+` operator has a lower precedence than the `%` operator.

```
print "%s" + "/" + "%s" + "/" + "%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

To fix it, add parentheses to the concatenation so that it is executed first, like so:

```
print ("%s" + "/" + "%s" + "/" + "%s") % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

Comment: I took this one because the explanation is more thorough although the first answer helped me get it, though it took me a while by myself looking at it. I will plus 1 the first answer when I have plus 1 powers.

Answer (score 4):

Because this:

```
print "%s" + "/" + "%s" + "/" + "%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

is the same as this, due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (notice the extra parenthesis)

```
print "%s" + "/" + "%s" + "/" + ("%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year))
```

Comment: I'm not following. Is it the pluses that is throwing it off, addition has higher precedence? Shouldn't this also throw off `print "%s" "/" "%s" "/" "%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
` since it is assumed they are being concatenated? Think you can explain a little more?

Comment: On second thought, I get it now. Spaces don't actually concatenate those strings together, it just prints those strings next to each other. The addition sign is acting as an operator as well as the percentage sign and confusing the order of it all.